# Creating a project, from Makefile to static/dynamic libraries in UNIX

Tags: c++, c, makefile, unix

Guys, would you describe a few things about c++ building blocks, on unix.

I want to create an application that links against static libs and dynamic libs (.so).

**Question 1:** *How do I create static library using gcc/g++ ?How do  I make my app link against it.*

**Question 2:** *How to specify it in the makefile, linking against static and dynamic libs, assuming that both libraries have header files*

Summary: I have been using makefiles and libraries for years, written by someone else. Thus every time I modified it, I simply cut-and-pasted things around, without really understanding it. Now I want to get down to the ground and understand the building/linking/Creating Makfile process in-depth.

*What is a good book describing these concepts in intimate details?*

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Static libraries are usually *archived* with the `ar` command. Once you build all of the object files (preferably with the `-fPIC` switch on GCC), you can run `ar` like so:

```
ar -rs archivename.a list.o of.o objects.o
```

The `man` page describes the options.

Dynamic libraries are built usually with the `-shared` switch to `gcc` or `ld` and the output file name with a `.so` extension.

Autotools handles this with the `libtool` program. I'm not familiar with its use.

Linking against these libraries can be done either by listing the libraries with the `-l` (ell) switch (such as `-lX` to link to `libX.so`) or by specifying them directly with absolute paths (such as adding `/usr/lib/libX.so` to your command). Static libraries are linked by specifying `-static` before `-l` or the appropriate absolute path to the `.a` archive.

Answer (score 11):

Bare bones Makefile for creating a static library consisting of the code in foo.cpp, bar.cpp:

```
PROJECT = library.a
OBJECTS = foo.o bar.o
CFLAGS  = -Wall -pedantic

all: $(PROJECT)

.cpp.o:
        g++ -c $(CFLAGS) $<

$(PROJECT): $(OBJECTS)
        libtool -o $(PROJECT) -static $(OBJECTS)
```

Bare bones Makefile for an app baz.cpp that static links to library.a:

```
PROJECT = baz
CFLAGS  = -Wall -pedantic
OBJECTS = baz.o

all: $(PROJECT)

.cpp.o:
        g++ -c $(CFLAGS) $<

$(PROJECT): $(OBJECTS) library.a
        g++ $(OBJECTS) -L. -llibrary -o $(PROJECT)
```

Dynamic library left, ahem, as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: What is -c flag in gcc. What about header file?

Comment: also, does $< mean, all cpp files? why do u need this case             .cpp.o:
                    g++ -c $(CFLAGS) $<     it doesn't see to be called anywhere? Thanks

Comment: -c means compile but do not link.  $< is the file name without the extention.  Check the man pages for gcc, make.  Header files have no place in a Makefile, unless they are a dependency.

Comment: In the first Makefile example one of the CFLAGS options is misspelt "-pendantic" should be "-pedantic"

Comment: Suffix rules are obsolete. http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Suffix-Rules.html#Suffix-Rules Remove the `.cpp.o:` target and you'll get the same behaviour from the makefile, through an implicit rule for generating the .o files.

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1: To create a static library from source files foo.c and bar.c, do this:

```
gcc -c foo.c
gcc -c bar.c
ar rc mylibrary.a foo.o bar.o
```

For more information about this, read the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) 
manual to learn how to use the compiler, and the linker via the compiler. The
[binutils manual](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/index.html) should also
be helpful.

Answer 2: The [GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) is pretty
good. To really learn about libraries and how they work, read the **Linkers and Loaders**
book by John R. Levine.

Static libraries are pretty simple, but shared libraries can be very hairy, depending
on the platform and the amount of portability you want and need. As an example, on
some systems static and shared libraries must be compiled with different options
to work properly (one must and the other must not be compiled with position independent
code). Whole frameworks of utilities have been developed to make this easier (libtool),
but they are not unproblematic themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Since you refer to gcc, I assume you're using GNU Make. The best documentation I've found for that is the [official manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/), which covers everything you need to know in easy-to-understand terms.

Answer (score 0):

When I was learning about Linux programming, [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder) helped me a lot. You can check Writing and Using Libraries section in [this pdf](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder/alp-ch02-writing-good-gnu-linux-software.pdf). It explains quite a bit about libraries in Linux.

Comment: That's a very good book, but I prefer something in conjunction with makefiles.

Answer (score -1):

you may want to have a look to this, too: http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO.html