# How do I compile a static library

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

I am trying to compile a static library. I followed the steps which were given in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598948/creating-a-project-from-makefile-to-static-dynamic-libraries-in-unix) but it is not working. Following is my makefile.

```
PROJECT = lq.a
OBJECTS = dlmalloc.o queue.o.o
CFLAGS  = -o -Wall -pedantic

all: $(PROJECT)

.c.o:
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS) $<

$(PROJECT): $(OBJECTS)
    libtool -o  $(PROJECT) -static $(OBJECTS)
```

And I get the following error.

```
libtool: unrecognized option `-o'
```

What is the correct way of writing this makefile?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the program `ar` [to create static libraries](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/static-libraries.html) using the following syntax:

```
 ar rcs my_library.a file1.o file2.o
```

So, in your case:

```
$(PROJECT): $(OBJECTS)
     ar rcs $(PROJECT) $(OBJECTS)
```

You can find an explanation of the options on [the man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ar), but basically:

- `r` says insert the given object files in to the archive (replacing any older versions of the same thing)
- `c` says create the archive if it isn't already there (normally this happens anyway, but this option suppresses the warning).
- `s` says to write an object-file index into the archive.

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is confusing; but I think that the `libtool -o  $(PROJECT) -static $(OBJECTS)` line (also mentioned in [objective c - Combine static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8170851/277826)) comes from Mac; and apparently the `libtool` there is **NOT** the same as the one on Linux:

[libtool or ar & ranlib - idevgames forums](http://www.idevgames.com/forums/thread-8330.html):

> I was using libtool to create a static library on OS X because that's what Xcode was doing, which seems to work fine. Then I go over to Linux and it chokes on my libtool command saying "libtool: unrecognized option '-o'". Looking at them, it seems like libtool on OS X and libtool on Linux are two completely different programs. ...
>   Followup: Yes, it appears that libtool on Linux is indeed glibtool on OS X. I get essentially the same output when doing "`glibtool --help`" on OS X as "`libtool --help`" on Linux.

Ok, that explains the difference - but still doesn't explain how `-o` can be an unrecognized option, when I've just seen it run from a Makefile on Linux! So I found this:

[bug-libtool mailing list (2001): Re: bug in libtool?](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-libtool/2001-09/msg00015.html)

> You need to set the mode before the mode options:
>
> $ libtool --mode=link --help
>    Usage: libtool [OPTION]... --mode=link LINK-COMMAND...

Oh dear... now what makes it especially confusing, is this note in `libtool --mode=link --help`:

```
$ libtool --mode=link --help
Usage: libtool [OPTION]... --mode=link LINK-COMMAND...
...

LINK-COMMAND is a command using the C compiler that you would use to create
a program from several object files.

The following components of LINK-COMMAND are treated specially: ...
  -all-static       do not do any dynamic linking at all ...
  -o OUTPUT-FILE    create OUTPUT-FILE from the specified objects ...
  -static           do not do any dynamic linking of uninstalled libtool libraries
...
All other options (arguments beginning with `-') are ignored.

Every other argument is treated as a filename.  Files ending in `.la' are
treated as uninstalled libtool libraries, other files are standard or library
object files.
...
If OUTPUT-FILE ends in `.a' or `.lib', then a standard library is created
using `ar' and `ranlib', or on Windows using `lib'.
```

So - if I **have** to specify a `LINK-COMMAND` - **and** at the same time, I specify an `OUTPUT-FILE` which ends in `.a`; which command should then run, `LINK-COMMAND` - or the `ar`+`ranlib` that extension `.a` specifies? Well - here's a terminal snippet, just testing the `bash` script logic of `libtool` - without any compilation (though an empty archive does get created):

```
$ libtool -o test.a
libtool: unrecognized option `-o'
libtool: Try `libtool --help' for more information.

$ libtool --mode=link -o test.a
libtool: link: unrecognized option `-o'
libtool: link: Try `libtool --help' for more information.

$ libtool --mode=link gcc -o test.a
libtool: link: ar cru test.a
libtool: link: ranlib test.a

$ libtool --mode=link ar -o test.a
libtool: link: unable to infer tagged configuration
libtool: link: specify a tag with `--tag'

$ cat $(which libtool) | grep "^# ### BEGIN LIBTOOL TAG CONFIG:"
# ### BEGIN LIBTOOL TAG CONFIG: disable-shared
# ### BEGIN LIBTOOL TAG CONFIG: disable-static
# ### BEGIN LIBTOOL TAG CONFIG: CXX
# ### BEGIN LIBTOOL TAG CONFIG: F77
# ### BEGIN LIBTOOL TAG CONFIG: FC
# ### BEGIN LIBTOOL TAG CONFIG: GCJ
# ### BEGIN LIBTOOL TAG CONFIG: RC
# ### BEGIN LIBTOOL TAG CONFIG: BINCC
# ### BEGIN LIBTOOL TAG CONFIG: BINCXX

## CC tag is not listed, but it will (eventually) be accepted:

$ libtool --mode=link ar --tag CC -o test.a
libtool: link: unable to infer tagged configuration
libtool: link: specify a tag with `--tag'

$ libtool --mode=link --tag CC ar -o test.a
libtool: link: ar cru test.a
libtool: link: ranlib test.a

$ libtool --tag=CC --mode=link ar -o test.a
libtool: link: ar cru test.a
libtool: link: ranlib test.a

$ libtool --tag=XX --mode=link ar -o test.a
libtool: ignoring unknown tag XX
libtool: link: ar cru test.a
libtool: link: ranlib test.a

$ libtool --tag=XX --mode=link whatevar -o test.a
libtool: ignoring unknown tag XX
libtool: link: ar cru test.a 
libtool: link: ranlib test.a

$ ls -la test.a 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 8 2013-04-17 23:12 test.a
```

So - not only do you have to specify a `--mode`, but if this mode is `link`, you MUST specify SOME sort of an argument (LINK-COMMAND) referring to a tool; BUT that LINK-COMMAND argument doesn't even need to exist as a *real* program - because you must specify an output file anyway; and if that output file ends on `.a`, it will enforce use of `ar`/`ranlib` *anyways*.

Also, should you have a problem with a tag - simply move the `--tag` argument before the LINK-COMMAND argument - and you can force `libtool` to run with a non-existing tag and a non-existing LINK-COMMAND (where it's operation is specified solely by the extension `.a` of the output file) - as long as the arguments are entered in the proper order for the `libtool` syntax; which I must admit isn't really documented in the script itself.

---

But to come back to the Mac `libtool -o  $(PROJECT) -static $(OBJECTS)` line, which would combine static libraries; if you try to do the same with proper static library `.a` files, you will notice that `libtool` pushes the `.a` archives *as such* in the output archive, *not* their constituent object files - so this output is not a valid ELF object anymore; here is an example of a corresponding Linux `libtool` line, with two proper library files I've generated:

```
$ readelf --syms libmy1.a
File: libmy1.a(my1.o)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 11 entries:
...
$ readelf --syms libmy2.a
File: libmy2.a(my2.o)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 12 entries:
...
$ libtool --mode=link --tag=CC ar -o libtest.a -static libmy1.a libmy2.a 
libtool: link: ar cru libtest.a libmy1.a libmy2.a 
libtool: link: ranlib libtest.a

$ readelf --syms libtest.a
readelf: Error: Not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start
readelf: Error: libtest.a(libmy1.a): Failed to read file header
readelf: Error: Not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start
readelf: Error: libtest.a(libmy2.a): Failed to read file header
```

So, as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11345669/277826) says - on Linux, use `ar` manually to unpack and pack again, to combine static libraries.

Hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Either use `libtool` or don't. If you're going to use it, then you should compile the individual files with `libtool --mode=compile` as well as linking with `libtool --mode=link`. If you're not going to use `libtool`, then your link should be done with `gcc` also, as pointed out in another answer. Also, have you tried `man libtool`?

Comment: I have tried `man libtool`, and it is not obvious at all, why should `-o` be an unrecognized option on Linux; but with the proper order of arguments, it can be recognized (see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16070483/277826)).

Comment: `libtool` does not accept an option `-o`, thus it's an "unrecognized option". Once you specify a `--mode=<something>` option to tell `libtool` what to do, then further options may be passed on to the tools `libtool` invokes. So `libtool --mode=link -o something` might be ok, but `libtool -o something` is not. Either way, you should either use `libtool` for both your compile and link stages, or not use it at all - you're just asking for confusion using `gcc` to compile but `libtool` to link.

Answer (score 2):

The following commands will build your static library:

```
$gcc -c file1.c -o libfile.o
$ar rcs libfile.a libfile.o
```